# Limit does not exist or limit does exist? What does the unevaluated output mean?

Tags: summation

From this short Mathematica program while investigating the convergence of the Dirichlet series for the Möbius function:

```
Clear[a, b, s, x];
s = 1/2 + 100*I;
Limit[1 - Sum[1/a^s, {a, 2, x}] + 
  Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^s, {a, 2, x}], {b, 2, x}], x -> Infinity]
```

I get the output:

[image]

where Out[186]= is left unevaluated.

> Does that mean that the limit exists but it is not known in the form of standard functions?

Comment: Usually unevaluated means that it doesn't have any rule that it can use to transform something into something else, otherwise it would have used that rule and then tried to see if there are even more rules that it knows.

Comment: `SumConvergence[1/a^s, a]` produces `False` and `Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^s, {a, 2, Infinity}], {b, 2, Infinity}]` produces a warning about the divergence.

Comment: Is it then also possible that the result is inconclusive?

Comment: For `x=100`, `x=300`,`x=400` the command `N[1 - Sum[1/a^s, {a, 2, x}] + 
  Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^s, {a, 2, x}], {b, 2, x}], 20]` results in `2.3467599530378114392 - 0.2374475269288298657 I`,`1.8074308438887463892 + 0.0811844979002236090 I`, and `2.4970344423667568855 - 0.4388452308824189010 I`. These results suggest the limit under consideration does not exist.

Comment: A `ListPlot` must always be suspect, but `s=1/2+100*I; t=Table[1-Sum[1/a^s,{a,2,x}]+ Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^s,{a,2,x}],{b,2,x}],{x,1,200}]//N; ListPlot[{Re[t],Im[t]}]` gives me a hint. Yes, I also thought that was a nice plot, but I tend to like visuals.

Comment: That is a nice ListPlot.

Comment: From the help of `Limit`: Limit returns unevaluated or an Interval when no limit can be found.

Comment: Ask it at MSE.This is rather math than Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,  we consider

```
 s = 1/2 + 100*I; Sum[1/a^s, {a, 2, x}]
```

> `-1 + HarmonicNumber[x, 1/2 + 100 I]`

Second (The crucial tool is an assumption.),

```
Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^s, {a, 2, x},Assumptions -> b \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {b, 2, x}]
```

> `(-1 + HarmonicNumber[x, 1/2 + 100 I])^2`

At last,

```
Limit[1 + (-1 + HarmonicNumber[x, 1/2 + 100 I])^2 - (-1 + 
HarmonicNumber[x, 1/2 + 100 I]), x -> Infinity]
```

> `ComplexInfinity`

Addition. The OP additionally requires  `a*b<=x`. In fact, this is not any restriction because the limit as `x->Infinity` is taken. The sum of a double series does not depend on an exhaustion. Since

```
ComplexExpand[1/Abs[(a*b)^(\[Sigma] + I*t)]]
```

> `(Sqrt[a^2] Sqrt[b^2])^-\[Sigma] E^(t Arg[a b])`

, the convergence depends only on `\[Sigma]`. It's more or less clear, that `\[Sigma]` should be greater than `1` to this end (I don't go into math deep.).
Therefore,

```
Sum[Sum[1/(a*b)^\[Sigma], {a, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Sigma] > 1 &&
 b \[Element] PositiveIntegers], {b, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Sigma] > 1]
```

> `1 - 2 Zeta[\[Sigma]] + Zeta[\[Sigma]]^2`

The same with `Sum[1/a^s, {a, 2, x}]`. Making use of Mathematica, we obtain the same answer as in MSE. The true convergence of a series is its absolute convergence. In view of it the series from the question are not absolutely convergent for `s = 1/2 + 100*I`.